# Generate jpeg-YCbCr tiles in geotiff file with jfif format instead pure jpeg format

Tags: gdal, geotiff

Currently, my app creates GeoTiff tiled files using following options:

- PROFILE=GeoTIFF
- TILED=YES
- BLOCKXSIZE=xxx
- BLOCKYSIZE=xxx
- COMPRESS=JPEG
- PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR
- JPEG_QUALITY=xx

However, some apps that use my served tiles do not work due to "invalid" JFIF format.

How can I force gdal to ensure JFIF format in GeoTiff tiles?

Answer (score 0):

See my own answer in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426732/generate-jpeg-ycbcr-tiles-in-geotiff-file-with-jfif-format-instead-pure-jpeg-for/428023#428023.

Basically, solution involves gdal code modifications